# Perforce swarm reviews allow you to diff between shelf updates. Is there a way to pull a specific revision?

Tags: perforce

In Perforce, the workflow is to create a review which creates a shelf. Then you continue working and can update the shelf as many times as you want. When you view it, you can see all the deltas and diff them.

Say my review has 12 revisions in it. Is there a way for me to unshelve the 6th revision?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click the dropdown in Swarm to select the different revisions of the review, you'll see that each revision is actually its own shelved changelist (Swarm automatically copies the shelf to a new numbered change each time you update it).  You can `p4 unshelve` any one of these changelists.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe it was in front of my face all this time. Only question remaining is if I wanted to get the 3rd revision out of say 8, would I need to grab 1, 2, then 3 -- or just 3? Deltas vs snapshot?

Comment: Shelves are snapshots, so just grab 3.